# container running in privileged mode

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I am new to Docker, I have a centos image running as a container inside the docker in privileged mode. I want to perform some operations on this image but I can't the root. how I can perform the operations on this image when I stated it in privileged mode. 
[this is the outcome when I run it in privileged mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca4ue.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by opening the new instance of the container by running this command `sudo docker exec -i -t a6f7c25afbbf /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

The `--privileged` option does not give you more privileges in the container, but gives the container more privileges. For example it can then access devices.

When you want to be root in the running container, you can add option `-u 0` to the `docker run` command.

Comment: I have used this command "docker run -u 0 --privileged  -ti -e container=docker  -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup  centos7-systemd /usr/sbin/init" but I still have the same problem. Am I using the correct command.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do inside of the running container?