# Why this error occurs 'You must run the container in the host namespace when running privileged mode'?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I have enabled user namespaces and now I wanted to run a docker container with --privileged flag, yes I know it's a bad practice but still I wanted to run that docker as --privileged.

But I can see this error pops-up, so was curious what is this error? What am I doing wrong?

`docker: Error response from daemon: privileged mode is incompatible to user namespaces. You must run the container in the host namespace when running privileged mode'`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This question should be asked instead on the Unix&Linux or SuperUser communities.  StackOverflow is for questions regarding programming.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I asked because I saw that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777169/container-running-in-privileged-mode

Comment: That question should also not be on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set `--userns host` on the docker run command.

From docker docs they said:

> If you enable user namespaces on the daemon, all containers are started with user namespaces enabled by default. In some situations, such as privileged containers, you may need to disable user namespaces for a specific container. To disable user namespaces for a specific container, add the `--userns=host` flag to the `docker container create`, `docker container run`, or `docker container exec` command.

`docker: Error response from daemon: privileged mode is incompatible to user namespaces. You must run the container in the host namespace when running privileged mode'`

It is pretty clear in the error, to run your container with `--previleged` you have to run your container in the host namespace not in the custom namespace.

Comment: Hi sahadat, thanks for answering,  can you please explain a bit more on host namespaces, I mean, is it true that the security provided by the user namespace will be useless if we use --userns=host?  Hope you got my question?

Comment: This clears everything. Thanks for answering this question.

Comment: For more you can read these two portion of docker docs, [Disable namespace remapping for a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#disable-namespace-remapping-for-a-container) and [User namespace known limitations](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#user-namespace-known-limitations)